# How to add the emojicon library in chatting android application?

Tags: android, emoji

I 'm using this library rockerhiue emojicon but tell me the programming step by step.

Comment: please share what have you tried so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[there are enough examples on Github](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon)

or [check is out](http://blog.csdn.net/wu928320442/article/details/43306575)
. it's written in chinese. be prepared